# How to run an update statement on post deploy script only once?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, continuous-integration

I want my update statement on my post deploy statement to run only once. How can I achieve this? I was guessing to use an If Not EXISTS wrapper. Is this correct.

i.e.

```
UPDATE table
   SET field1 = 'X',
       field2 = 'X'
 WHERE field_id = 1;
```

Comment: Why would that statement run more than once?

Comment: Would it not run upon deployment unless I wrap it around an if condition? correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I don't know what you're deployment process is, so no idea. All I have to go on is a single SQL Script; which would only run once when you ran it.

Comment: We are using continuous integration and managing data changes in our Post-deploy. It is a very simple code change but had made me think twice whether it would need something around it to make sure it only runs once...